# Getting an error "use of closed network connection"

Tags: mongodb, http, go, database-connection, mongodb-atlas

My application stack consist of Golang for backend programming & MongoDB Atlas Free Tier for database. I am trying to trigger events from Stripe CLI and my GoLang programs updates a bunch of tables in MongoDB Atlas based on certain validations. This seems to work fine for the most part. But at certain times in the process, I am facing the below error while updating data into Mongo Collections.

> connection(xxxxx-shard-00-02.ka3rc.mongodb.net:xxx[-15])
> incomplete read of message header: read tcp
> xxx.xxx.x.xx:xxxxx->xx.xx.xxx.xxx:xxxxx: use of closed network connection

I am trying the use the same mongo client that i opened when control enters my Go program to execute all queries within the application.

Do anyone know the reason why we would face this error? Could this be due to Mongo Atlas restricting the number of requests per minute for free tier? This issue happens so randomly and i am not able to determine any pattern when this occurs.

Comment: Most probably you did not set connection timeout  from the app driver and server keep alive timeout  close the connection before application to understand , try adding maxTimeMS(5000) to the connection uri

Comment: I guess you are correct. I think it is got something to do with the time taken to execute all queries using the same client. Once i updated the timeout on my connection string to 40s, I don't seem to face this issue. Btw, do you know the default time out value for a connection?

Comment: the default go driver  timeout settings available here: https://docs.mongodb.com/drivers/go/current/fundamentals/connection/

Answer (score 0):

From the go driver client options page:

https://pkg.go.dev/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver@v1.8.0/mongo/options#ClientOptions

Most of timers  are 0 by default :
( ConnectTimeout , MaxConnIdleTime , SocketTimeout )

This mean that in some cases server can close the connection , but the application driver to still not be aware , so it is recommended those timeouts from the client side to be set explicitly during connection init phase.